# JavaScript factory function modify variable outside closure scope

Tags: javascript, closures

Why variable "OnDone" stays unmodified inside factory scope?

```js
const foo = () => {
  let OnDone = null;

  const Do = function() {
    console.log(OnDone);
    if (typeof OnDone === 'function')
      OnDone();
  }

  return {
    Do,
    OnDone
  };
}


let f = foo();
f.OnDone = () => {
  console.log('OnDone');
};

f.Do();
```

Outputs null.
https://jsfiddle.net/xe4j9hmc/6/

Comment: scope of `foo` and the `f` are different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers already explained what the problem is but I figured it would be useful to see a simplified example of the issue:

```js
var foo = null;
var obj = {foo};
obj.foo = 42;
console.log(foo);
```

Here as well, logging the value of `foo` will print `null`. Assigning a new value to the `obj.foo` **property** does not change the **variable** `foo`. That's because when we create the object with `{foo}`, a *copy of the value* of `foo` is assigned to the property.

In your specific case you want the assignment to the property to also change the variable. You can do this via a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) (and we add a getter for good measure):

```js
const foo = () => {
  let OnDone = null;

  const Do = function() {
    console.log(OnDone);
    if (typeof OnDone === 'function')
      OnDone();
  }

  return {
    Do,
    get OnDone() {
      return OnDone;
    },
    set OnDone(value) {
      OnDone = value;
    },
  };
}


let f = foo();
f.OnDone = () => {
  console.log('OnDone');
};

f.Do();
```

Now when you assign to the property `f.OnDone` we are really executing the setter function which in turn updates the variable value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can get rid of 'this'. I even didn't know about get/set in js.

Answer (score 2):

`let onDone = null` defines a variable `onDone` inside `foo` function scope not a property, but when you do

`f.onDone`  it adds value to `onDone` property on `f` which can be accessed using `this.onDone` but in your code you're using `onDone` which still refers to `onDone` defined in local scope

---

You probably wanted to do this

```js
function foo(){
  this.OnDone = null;

  const Do = function() {
  console.log(this.OnDone);
  if (typeof this.OnDone === 'function')
    this.OnDone();
  }

  return {Do, onDone:this.OnDone};
}


let f = new foo();
f.OnDone = () => {
  console.log('OnDone');
};

f.Do();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   return { OnDone };
```

equals ...

```
   return { onDone: onDone };
```

or in other words: The local variable `onDone` gets resolved, and the object reference it resolves to gets stored in the returned objects `onDone` property. Both will reference the same thing, * but* if you reassign either the local variable or the objects property, this will change the * reference*, thus the property and the variable will reference different things then.

To resolve the problem, change the object itself:

```
 const context = { onDone }
 context.Do = function () {
   // Access context.onDone here
 };

 return context;
```

Or, as an alternative, as `f.Do()` will call `Do` with `this` being `f`, you can access the objects property as `this.OnDone` from within the `Do` function.